# How to use an interval and a function to change the innerHTML of a div?

Tags: javascript, function, innerhtml, intervals

So I want the `innerHTML` to the div("gamediv") to change when the timer hits 0. In the div("gamediv"), there is another div that is supposed to trigger the function. But the way it is now, the timer starts on load, and the `g1change()` never happens.

```js
var count = 4;

var counter = setInterval(timer, 1000);

function timer() {
  count -= 1;
  if (count === 0) {
    g1change();
    clearInterval(counter);
  }

  document.getElementById("gamediv").innerHTML = '<center><p id="countdown">' + count + '</p></center>';
}

function g1change() {
  document.getElementById("gamediv").innerHTML = '<h1 id="g1text">Click the button to the right!</h1><div onclick="correct()" class="g1button"></div><div onclick="wrong()" class="g1button">g1button</div>'
}
```

```html
<div class="gamediv" id="gamediv">
  <div onclick="timer()" class="start">
    <h1 class="starttext">Start!</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `g1change()` is called, but the script will continue to execute the rest of `timer()` ;)

Answer (score 1):

The function `g1change()`  is getting invoked. As the script is continued to execute the `div`'s content is getting updated.

Either you can use else or need to break the function call after the `clearInterval()` method is invoked.

*but the timer still starts on load.*

Don't invoke `setInterval()` on the page load. Here I have create a new function i.e. `callTimer()` which is getting invoked on button click

```js
var count = 4;
var counter;

function callTimer() {
  counter = setInterval(timer, 1000);
}

function timer() {
  count -= 1;
  if (count === 0) {
    g1change();
    clearInterval(counter);
    //Termite the function
    return;
  }

  document.getElementById("gamediv").innerHTML = '<center><p id="countdown">' + count + '</p></center>';
}

function g1change() {
  document.getElementById("gamediv").innerHTML = '<h1 id="g1text">Click the button to the right!</h1><div onclick="correct()" class="g1button"></div><div onclick="wrong()" class="g1button"></div>'
}
```

```html
<div class="gamediv" id="gamediv">
  <div onclick="callTimer()" class="start">
    <h1 class="starttext">Start!</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, that fixed the function problem i had, but the timer still starts on load.

Comment: I've tried that, but if i do this, the timer doesn't stop. It goes from 0 to -1 and so on.

Comment: In the start yes, but then it starts on load, if i do it in local, the timer doesn't stop.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var count = 4;

var counter = setInterval(timer, 1000);

function timer() {
  count -= 1;
  //console.log(count);
  if (count === 0) {
    g1change();
   
  }else{
    document.getElementById("gamediv").innerHTML = '<center><p id="countdown">' + count + '</p></center>';
  }
}

function g1change() {
  document.getElementById("gamediv").innerHTML = '<h1 id="g1text">Click the button to the right!</h1><div onclick="correct()" class="g1button"></div><div onclick="wrong()" class="g1button">g1button</div>';
   clearInterval(counter);
}
```

```html
<div class="gamediv" id="gamediv">
  <div onclick="timer()" class="start">
    <h1 class="starttext">Start!</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

You have made some logical mistakes refer to the above code.